# Value disappears after assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to assign something to a variable in the `__init__()` function, but when I try to call it, the value of the variable disappears.

Here is the simplified code:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        if condition 1:
            self.a = some variables
        elif condition 2:
            self.b = some variables

    def method1(self):
        do somethings
        return self.a, self.b
```

When I try to call `method1()` after satisifying `condition1` and `condition2` (I have set a breakpoint to check whether `self.a` and `self.b` exist at the end of `__init__()`), only `self.a` has been assigned a value, but `self.b` has no values being assigned.

I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: You're going to need to show actual code rather than pseudo-code

Comment: Your `if` and `elif` structure short-circuits if `condition 1` is met, so `self.b` will not get assigned

Comment: `elif` executes ONLY if the previous condition are FALSE

Comment: I got it now. Because I have firstly initiated the `Class A` and it satisfied the `condition 1` but didn't satisfy `condition 2`. Then I initiated the `Class A` again, but this time it satisfied the `condition 2` but didn't satisfy `condition 1`. So `self.a` and `self.b` are in different variables. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is probably only meeting condition 1 (and defining `self.a` there), but not meeting condition 2 (therefore not defining `self.b`).
You can initialize them at the beginning of the `__init__` method with something like `self.a = None`